# How to specify wildcards in proxy exceptions in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, proxy

IE supports wildcards in proxy exceptions like:
`mycompany-*; *.mydomain.org; 192.168.1.*`

What I have to insert in the proxy exceptions in Firefox? I read wildcard * is not supported at all, but found no solution.

And how can I exclude a few sites from a global wildcarded domain?

eg. I have excluded `*.mydomain.com` from proxy, but then I have to enable proxy for `site1.mydomain.com`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Came across the most complete reference on this: http://www-archive.mozilla.org/quality/networking/docs/aboutno_proxy_for.html

In summary:

- Any domain in the list is matched using "ends with" logic, so "site.com" would match "mysite.com" in url. (Wildcard at the beginning of a domain is redundant and ignored.)
- IP address can only be expressed in CIDR format and are only matched if literal IP is used in the url, i.e. no DNS lookup is performed before checking this list.
- If the list contains `<local>` and the domain part of the url contains no dot, then proxy is not used.
- Wildcard not at the beginning and IPv6 addresses are not supported

If your requirements cannot be satisfied by above, writing a PAC file is the only way.

Comment: The link in the answer ["No Proxy For"](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/quality/networking/docs/aboutno_proxy_for.html) is marked as being "out of date". A fresh version: [network.proxy.no_proxies_on](http://kb.mozillazine.org/No_proxy_for). That page describes the value of attribute `network.proxy.no_proxies_on`, so it is possible to open the configuration at URL "about:config" and edit the variable there instead of [going through the menu system](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/connection-settings-firefox).

Answer (score 12):

You can define wildcards with the CIDR notation. For example:

```
10.0.0.0/8
```

specifies the range from `10.0.0.0` up to `10.255.255.255`

See for more information: [CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)

Answer (score 6):

I think you can just add the domain e.g.

```
.mydomain.org
```

Will pick up any variant.  I don't know about `mycompany-*`

I believe it also supports ranges e.g. `192.168.1.0/8`

Answer (score 3):

I was faced with a similar problem (however it was only for *local* machines on our network)

I needed to bypass the proxy for all our local machines. These start in the format abcXXX where `XXX` is a value from 000 - 999

For example one development server may be hosted on abc303 and the other on abc909.

We tried the [CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) method in our proxy execptions as all machines had an IP address in the 10.0.0.0/8 however, we still faced issues.

We manged to fix this by adding

```
<local>
```

to our proxy exceptions

I couldn't find a lot of information on this but it is mentioned in Mozilla's Bug 72444 - [Proxy: "bypass proxy server for local addresses"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72444#c77) bug request.

Comment: Yes, it seems almost all variations of CIDR specification are broke in firefox, but <local> will work for 10.0.0.0/8 and 192.168.0.0/16 (and possibly 172.16.0.0/12)

Comment: This does not work because the match won't be done on the IP address (or a masked IP address) if a hostname is used in the URL - even if the hostname in the URL resolves to the IP address.